# Are permissions like "---r-xr-x" useful?

Tags: permissions, unix-philosophy

Would a file permission tuple of "---r-xr-x", or something else without owner usability yet still with group/other usability ever be useful in the real world?  I would love to see some use cases!

**NOTE:** I can see I'm being downvoted, so let me clarify.  This is an *ABSTRACT* question, not one specific to my needs.

Comment: Design your system by your needs, don't do it revsersely.

Comment: Interesting question. The only thing I could think of would be a case where the owner account got compromised, but by that point the account shouldn't be active anyway, or if it's still necessary to investigate at least have login ability removed.  Otherwise, there's no practical application, it seems.  If the owner belongs to a group, they can still access the file that way, within group permissions, of course.

Comment: Potentially, `---r-xr-x` could be to make the file read-only, non-modifiable even by owner. But note that root user or if ACL permissions are set - there's still a way to edit the file. If the file is in the directory where owner has permissions to write in the directory, they can remove the file, or read contents, change the contents, and overwrite the file with new file (think vim for example).